# Schema problems with Fiona

Tags: python, fiona

I have been getting a `“ValueError: Record does not match collection schema:”` error a lot recently. I have been using

```
form fiona import collection
form shapely.geometry import mapping, shape 
with collection(path_in, "r") as input:
    schema = input.schema.copy()
    with collection(path_out, "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema) as output:
        list = []
        for f in input:
            list.append(shape(f['geometry']))
    do stuff with shapely 
    output.write({'geometry': mapping(somethingIDid), 'properties':{'somethingFromSchema':'somethingToMakeThisValid'}})
```

I thought I was extracting the schema form the input file so the records I am writing should match the original schema. Right? Is there a better way to work with shapely?

Comment: Please don't import and use the collection ctor. Import fiona and use fiona.open() as shown in the manual. Your code will be more future proof that way.

Comment: Without seeing the full text of the error (Fiona includes a repr of the collection schema and the feature properties in the exception message: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/src/fiona/ogrext.pyx#L1105), I can only guess what's wrong. Can you update your question with more info and actual values instead of somethingIDid and somethingFromSchema?